# Forking a private repository on Github

Tags: github

If you fork a private repository on Github is your fork made private by default?

Comment: can't you just try it and see?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, so you may not worring about uncovering your code.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, I have tried this and the fork is private